# Return multiple rows with subquery in SQL select clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to return multiple rows in a SQL select clause, when your subquery does not have a join/key field? My query currently looks like this. I'm wanting to return list of users and a list of contracts when there is no key between the users and contracts.

There is a handful of users, but a whole lot of contracts and I'm wanting to generate a list of each contractID next to each userID.

```
select 
userid,
(select contractid from contracts) as contractid
from users
```

New here, but the suggestion for a cross join did what I wanted. thanks!

Comment: If you want to associate contracts with users, you must have a join field. If, on the other hand, you just want a list of user IDs and contract IDs, you can use the UNION ALL keyword.

Comment: Do a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: "Is there a way to return multiple rows in a Scalar Subquery?" -- No, but you can use other strategies to get the result you want.

Comment: Use the str_agg function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 EDIT: Never mind after re-reading your question I think I had the wrong idea, but I'll leave the comment here just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all possible combinations of `users` with `constracts` by performing a `CROSS JOIN`. For example:

```
select 
  u.*,
  c.*
from users u
cross join contracts c
```

You can, then, filter the result by appending `WHERE <condition>` as needed.